# Create array based on another arrays C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, linq, nested-loops

I am trying to create an array based on the ones that I have. I have two arrays which look like this
sample array A:  `{AB01, AB01, AB01, AB02, AB02, AB02, AB03, AB01}`

sample array B: `{10, 10, 20, 10, 20, 20, 40, 10}`

Both arrays are dynamic so provided data is just a sample data. Same indexes in both arrays creates a pair: so for example: pair 1: `AB01 10` , pair 2: `AB01 10` and so on. Based on those two arrays I want to create third array which will represent indexes but including duplicates. So I want my third array to look like this:

array (3) C:  `{10, 10, 20, 30, 40, 40, 50, 10}`

FYI I cannot use LINQ 4+

I tried nested loop over the arrays but I do not get the expected result.

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrayA.Length; i++){
    for(int j = i + 1; j < arrayA.Length; j++){
     if(arrayA[i] == arrayA[j] && arrayB[i] == arrayB[j]){
       arrayC.Insert(i, 10 * (i+1));
     }
     else
      arrayC.Insert(i, 10 * (i+2));
    }
}
```

As I mentioned I expext my array C to be indexes of each element but I want to include duplicates:

array (3) C:
 `{10, 10, 20, 30, 40, 40, 50, 10}`

EDIT:

As the result is not clear.

If there was no duplicates in the arrays I would want my array C to look like this:
 `{10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80}`
It means that each pair eg(AB01, 10) will be given index 10 in array C.
But when it comes to duplicates array C will look different.

Pair AB01 - 10 appears as first so I want to give it index 10. And because it appears three times at position: 0, 1 and 7 I want number 10 to be at those positions in array C. Next on I have pair AB01 - 20 it appears only one time at position 2 and values are different than in pair to so I want to give it index 20. And so on.

Comment: "Same indexes in both arrays creates a pair" So why don't use a class with two properties and use that in a single array?

Comment: It's not clear how those two input arrays result in the expected output.  Can you explain exactly why you expect that output?  Specifically where does the 50 come from?

Comment: Please, let's start from the *relevant examples*; say, we have `A = {10, 20, 30, 10, 10, 30}` and `B = {10, 10, 40, 30, 10}` what is the expected array `C` and why?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko arrays `A` and `B` and `C`  must be the same length.

Comment: So: for each pair, if it has been encountered before, use the already allocated "index", otherwise create a new one as (previous index) + 10. Right?

Comment: @KlausGütter that is correct

Answer (score 1):

As written in the comments, a re-formulation of the task is:

> for each pair, if it has been encountered before, use the already
> allocated "index", otherwise create a new one as (previous index) +
> 10.

You need to remember the already assigned indexes, e.g. in a `Dictionary<(string, int), int>`, mapping a pair to the index. In addition. you need to keep track of the highest index assigned so far.

```
var arrayA = new string[] { "AB01", "AB01", "AB01", "AB02", "AB02", "AB02", "AB03", "AB01"};
var arrayB = new int[] {10, 10, 20, 10, 20, 20, 40, 10};


var assignedIndexes = new Dictionary<(string, int), int>();
var highestIndex = 0;

var result = new int[arrayA.Length];
for (var i = 0; i < arrayA.Length; i++)
{
    var tuple = (arrayA[i], arrayB[i]);
    if (!assignedIndexes.TryGetValue(tuple, out var index))
    {
        index = highestIndex + 10;
        assignedIndexes.Add(tuple, index);
        highestIndex = index;
    }
    result[i] = index;
}

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
```

Prints: 10, 10, 20, 30, 40, 40, 50, 10

If you cannot use ValueTuples, too, replace them by Tuples:

```
var assignedIndexes = new Dictionary<Tuple<string, int>, int>();
var tuple = Tuple.Create(arrayA[i], arrayB[i]);
```